# Hide a class or javascript link on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, class, mobile, transition, responsive

I have some transitions on my web site, and everything is fine on desktop view. But when I try to see my website on cellphone the transitions are really slow, and take a lot of time to load the content.How can I hide (or something like that) the javascript links that calls the transitions?, or maybe hide the classes which calls the javascripts...the classes are like:

```
-top, -opacity
```

etc...this classes belong to this plugin 
http://www.cwdesigns.de/jquery-scrollflow-plugin.html

please help me!!, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

### Use Media Query

Write those classes with transitions in a media query interval for a range of large screens,

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) { 
  .top {

  }
  .opacity {

  }
}
```

Comment: I'm using this plugin, which contains the classes... http://www.cwdesigns.de/jquery-scrollflow-plugin.html

Comment: Can you share your script file or show how you invoke the plugin function.

Comment: it's just like a said before...I just link the javascript file on my index page...and then I use the classes -top or -opacity etc ....all the code it's on the javascript file..there is no css file.